# How to create a grid density overlay layer with folium and leaflet in python?

Tags: python, leaflet, openstreetmap, folium

I have a csv file with the path to a bunch of pictures, the name of the animal and the geo coordinates. To represent this data, instead of using markers, I would like to create a grid overlay layer exactly like the one you see below.

[image]

How can I create a grid overlay layer? I could not find any code examples to help me out.

Comment: You could use a choropleth map.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I see that choropleth maps user geojson. How can I know the min and the max coordinates of the world map to generate the polygons in a square shape?

Comment: The valid range of latitude in degrees is -90 and +90 for the southern and northern hemisphere respectively. Longitude is in the range -180 and +180 specifying coordinates west and east of the Prime Meridian, respectively.

Comment: *Oh, thanks! I see that choropleth maps user geojson* Yes, it does.